# How to call a variable between the strings in applescript

Tags: variables, applescript, iterm2

Below is the apple script for opening multiple tab need to call the variable ' i ' between the string how this can be done in bash we use $i to call the variable.

```
repeat with i from 1 to 2

tell application "iTerm 2"
    tell current window
        create tab with default profile
    end tell
    tell current tab of current window
        set _new_session to last item of sessions
    end tell
    tell _new_session
        select
        set name to d(i)-tech`
```

Tried to called using Parentheses and $ before the variable 'i'

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation in AppleScript is done with the `&` operator.

So, your `set` statement should read:
`set name to "d" & i & "-tech"`.